# Assigning increment to array

Tags: php

While hunting down a bug in my PHP application, I came accross some odd behavior. Here's a code sample:

```
$x = array(array('t1' => 'a', 't2' => 'b', 't3' => 'c', 't4' => 'd', 't5' => 'e'),
           array('t1' => 'a', 't2' => 'b', 't3' => 'c', 't4' => 'd', 't5' => 'e'),
           array('t1' => 'a', 't2' => 'b', 't3' => 'c', 't4' => 'd', 't5' => 'e'),
           array('t1' => 'a', 't2' => 'b', 't3' => 'c', 't4' => 'd', 't5' => 'e'));
$test = array();

$i = 0;
foreach ($x as $key => $value) {
    $test[$i] = $value;
    $test[$i]['t6'] = $i++;
}
print_r($test);
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [t1] => a
            [t2] => b
            [t3] => c
            [t4] => d
            [t5] => e
            [t6] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [t1] => a
            [t2] => b
            [t3] => c
            [t4] => d
            [t5] => e
            [t6] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [t1] => a
            [t2] => b
            [t3] => c
            [t4] => d
            [t5] => e
            [t6] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [t1] => a
            [t2] => b
            [t3] => c
            [t4] => d
            [t5] => e
            [t6] => 3
        )

)
```

What I get instead is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [t1] => a
            [t2] => b
            [t3] => c
            [t4] => d
            [t5] => e
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [t1] => a
            [t2] => b
            [t3] => c
            [t4] => d
            [t5] => e
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [t1] => a
            [t2] => b
            [t3] => c
            [t4] => d
            [t5] => e
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [t1] => a
            [t2] => b
            [t3] => c
            [t4] => d
            [t5] => e
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [t6] => 3
        )

)
```

When I change the line

```
$test[$i]['t6'] = $i++;
```

to

```
$test[$i]['t6'] = $i;
$i++;
```

it works as expected.

I'm trying to understand the cause of the problem so I can avoid it in similar cases. Could someone please explain why the increment is not assigned properly here?

(By the way, the same problem exists for the decrement. Maybe that's a useful peace of information.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer myself in the end. The reason the assigment seems not to work is that the operator precedence of ++ and (array) is the same and the associativity is right. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

This means $i is incremented before it is used as an array key. This means the next iteration of the foreach loop will overwrite that same key in the line

```
$test[$key] = $value;
```

The only time this does not happen is in the last iteration of the loop.

As a fix, I could either write

```
$test[$i++]['t6'] = $i;
```

which looks kind of weird and is counter-intuitive, or I can go with my original fix

```
$test[$i]['t6'] = $i;
$i++;
```

which is a little less elegant, but easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You have a semantic error, try $key instead of $i

```
$x = array(array('t1' => 'a', 't2' => 'b', 't3' => 'c', 't4' => 'd', 't5' => 'e'),
           array('t1' => 'a', 't2' => 'b', 't3' => 'c', 't4' => 'd', 't5' => 'e'),
           array('t1' => 'a', 't2' => 'b', 't3' => 'c', 't4' => 'd', 't5' => 'e'),
           array('t1' => 'a', 't2' => 'b', 't3' => 'c', 't4' => 'd', 't5' => 'e'));
$test = array();

$i = 0;
foreach ($x as $key => $value) {
    $test[$key] = $value;
    $test[$key]['t6'] = $i++;
}
print_r($test);

?>
```

Comment: This does fix the problem. However, in my code, I do not assign every key/value pair of the original array ($x) to the new array ($test). So in many cases, $key is not the same as $i.